# wp-cli table output to a variable -> wlack webhook

Tags: bash, wp-cli

I am trying to send the output of a wp-cli command to a slack webhook.
WP-cli outputs tables with, in this case, plugin updates.

The command for this is:
`$ wp plugin update --all --dry-run --format=table`

The normal output is:

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------+
| name                                    | status         | version | update_version |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------+
| aryo-activity-log                       | active-network | 2.6.1   | 2.7.0          |
| autoptimize                             | inactive       | 2.8.3   | 2.8.4          |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------+
```

But, when I put the table output into a variable, and echo the variable, all table markup has been stripped:
`Available plugin updates: name status version update_version aryo-activity-log active-network 2.6.1 2.7.0 autoptimize inactive 2.8.3 2.8.4`

The complete script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
updatesplugins=$(wp plugin update --all --dry-run --format=table)
echo $updatesplugins;
```

I am stuck at this point.
Why does bash strip all these -, + and | characters? And how to keep this in its original state zo I can send the table/variable to, in this case, a slack webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try redirecting the output to a text file instead of a variable.
A variable usually stores data in a single line. Try something like this -

```
$(wp plugin update --all --dry-run --format=table) > updatesplugins.txt
cat updatesplugins.txt # or use it in some other command
```